# PHP: Get the caller subclass in the base class static method

Tags: php, class, static

I have the following classes:

```
class Base {
    static $static_var = 'base_static';
    public static function static_init() {
        // HERE, I want to get the caller extended class.
        echo __CLASS__.'<br/>';
        // HERE, I want to get the caller extended static variable.
        echo static::$static_var.'<br/>';
        // Do some initialization works depends on the static_var.
        // ...
    }
};

class Children extends Base {
    // overridden
    static $static_var = 'extended_static';
};

// Call Now
Children::static_init();

/** echos:
Base
base_static
*/

/** I want to export:
Children
extended_static
*/
```

I may extend the Base class to many sub-classes.

So in my sub-classes, I can define the static arguments by static variables of their own.

Is there a way to do so? Or how should I design my classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is 'get_called_class()', as per the php.net definition for get_called_class():

" Gets the name of the class the static method is called in. "

So the end code would be like:

```
class Base {
  static $static_var = 'base_static';
  public static function static_init() {
    $caller_class = get_called_class();
    // HERE, I want to get the caller extended class.
    echo $caller_class . '<br/>';
    // HERE, I want to get the caller extended static variable.
    echo $caller_class::$static_var.'<br/>';
    // Do some initialization works depends on the static_var.
    // ...
  }
};
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php